# I have a conflict with types using generic interfaces and classes with c#

Tags: c#, interface

I'm introducing in C# Generic interfaces and clases, and there's a problem that I couldn't deal with, and I'll share the code here for if anyone could help me.

```
enum ListError
{
    Ok = 0,
    NoMemory,
    ErrorPosition
}

interface IList<T>
{

    int End();

    ListError Insert<T>(T x, int p);

}

class ListArrays<T>: IList<T>
{
    const int MAX = 100;

    T [] data = new T[MAX];
    int last = 0;

    public int End()
    {
        return last+1;
    }

    ListError Insert<T>(T x, int p)
    {
        if (last >= MAX)
            return ListError.NoMemory;
        if (p > last || p < 0)
            return ListError.ErrorPosition;
        for (int q = last; q >= p; q--)
            data[q] = data[q - 1];
        last++;
        data[p] = x;
        return ListError.Ok;
    }
}
```

I'm fighting with a compile time error in the line

```
data[p] = x;
```

which states:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'T [c:\Users\MartinD_PC\Documents\VisualStudio 2013\Projects\Aho_Hopcroft_Ullman\Aho_Hopcroft_Ullman\Chapter_2\ListaArreglos.cs(9)]' to 'T'
```

Comment: Please read compiler warnings; you should have gotten a warning that explained the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `ListError Insert<T>(T x, int p)` to `ListError Insert(T x, int p)`. The compiler thinks you are specifying a new type `T` in `Insert`.

Note: `Insert` needs to be public (or explicit, since it's a interface implementation). Otherwise, that would be a another compilation error.

Comment: Please mark this as answered if you are happy with it. Thanks.